# Sending 2D and 3D shadowmaps to shaders

Tags: opengl, glsl, shadow, texture-mapping

I'm trying to implement shadow mapping for my simple engine and i've figured out I should combine Omnidirectional Shadow Mapping (cubemap for point lights) with 2d mapping (for directional and spot lights).

My uniform block looks like this:

```
#define MAX_LIGHTS 128
//...
struct Light
{
   //light data...
};
//...
layout (std140) uniform Lights
{
    int lightCount; //how many lights were passed into the shader (from 0 to MAX_LIGHTS)
    Light lights[MAX_LIGHTS];
};
```

I have two questions for you.

1. Are *sampler* objects costly? Is the following code optimal for multiple lights?

   ```
   sampler2D shadowMaps2D[MAX_LIGHTS];
   samplerCube shadowCubemaps[MAX_LIGHTS];
   //...
   if (lights[index].type == POINT_LIGHT)
       CalculateShadow(shadowCubemaps[lights[index].shadowMapNr]);
   else
       CalculateShadow(shadowMaps2D[lights[index].shadowMapNr]);
   ```

   Only *lightCount* amount of the objects would be actually filled with a texture. We're stuck with a lot of undefined *samplers* and I think it can cause some problems.
2. If I understand correctly, I mustn't declare *sampler* in uniform blocks. So am I really forced to cycle through all of my shaders and update samplers each time the shadow maps get updated? It's a waste of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are *sampler* objects costly?

That question is a bit misleading since the `sampler` data types in GLSL are only *opaque handles* which reference the *texture units*. What is costly is the actual sampling operation. Also, the number of texture units a particular shade stage is limited. The spec only guarantees 16. Since you can't reuse the same unit for different sampler types, this would limit your `MAX_LIGHTS` to just 8.

However, one seldom needs arrays of samplers. Instead, you can use [array textures](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Array_Texture), which will allow you to store all of your shadow maps (per texture type) in a single texture object, and you will need only one sampler for it.

Having said all that I still think that your light count is completely unrealistic. Applying 128 shadow maps in real time won't work even on the fastest GPUs out there...

> If I understand correctly, I mustn't declare *sampler* in uniform blocks.

Correct.

> So am I really forced to cycle through all of my shaders and update samplers each time the shadow maps get updated? It's a waste of time!

No. The sampler uniforms only need to be updated if the *index of the texture unit you want to sample from* changes (which is ideally never). Not when a different texture is bound, and not when some texture contents change.